# Chrome on Windows: is there a keyboard shortcut to that brings up the contextual menu?

Tags: windows, keyboard, google-chrome

When typing in a text area in Chrome (e.g. in Gmail), I constantly have to reach the mouse to get spelling suggestions for a word that underlined in red, or to add a word to the dictionary.

Is there a keyboard shortcut that would show the contextual menu in that case, so you don't have to use the mouse to pick a suggestion or add a word to the dictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually both the context menu key (to the left of the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key) and the combination <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> bring up the context menu.

However, if the application is relying on the mouse pointer's location when opening the context menu to provide additional entries (such as the spell-checking stuff), then you can't do much. IE7Pro's spell checker does that too and it annoys me. Word gets this right (but for Word it's a core feature, not something tacked on which looks nice on a feature list).

Actually, I'd consider that a bug in the respective application as the *context* for the context menu is *not* the mouse pointer when opening the menu by keyboard. Especially not if it's inside a text input field.

But short of reporting a bug to the Chrome developers there probably isn't much you can do. Maybe you could whip up some ugly Autohotkey evilness which moves the mouse pointer to the location of the text cursor when pressing the context menu key. But since browsers don't use native controls but instead render everything on their own you probably can't do much from there either (as it may well be impossible to figure out where the text cursor is located).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is fixed in Chromium so hopefully will make it into Chrome soon:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=282598

Comment: This is fixed in Chrome now.

Answer (score 1):

Using the keyboard select the word (if it is the word before the cursor Ctrl+Shift+Arrow-Left) then hit the contextual menu key.

Chrome version 53.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> seems to do the trick.

Comment: @Ken Thanks for the answer, but Shift-F10 seems to be equivalent to clicking on the background on the text area, but is not equivalent to right clicking on a word, even if the cursor is on that word.

Comment: @Alessandro: it works for me, with the latest Dev release of Chrome. Shift+F10 opens the contextual menu of the textbox, with the replacement suggestions for the word that has the cursor on it.

Comment: It seems a bit finicky about focus, but if I cursor over a misspelled word (just not right after it, strangely) and hit shift-F10, I do see the list of suggested corrections.  I'm on Chromium "5.0.367.0 (43244)", so maybe it's a recent fix?